# Can we create pull request from master branch to master branch in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Can we create pull request from master branch to master branch in Azure devops because our team will work on directly in master branch and we need to code review and approval method also.

Comment: Hi devendar, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

No this isn't how git works. You would have to branch off of master and then PR these branches back into master. Committing directly to master is not a recommended practice

Answer (score 1):

Contributions to a source code repository that uses a distributed version control system are commonly made by means of a pull request, also known as a ***merge request***.

The contributor requests that the project maintainer pulls the source code change, hence the name "pull request". The maintainer has to merge the pull request if the contribution should become part of the source base.

A pull request can be accepted or rejected by maintainers. Once the pull request is reviewed and approved, it is merged into the repository.

The above is how to pull request works.

We can push empty commits via `git commit --allow-empty -m 1`, But for your situation, even no empty commits(Because the source branch and target branch always the same), so of course the pull request will not be able to created.

Another thing will clearly tell you the reason:

If you use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to create Pull Request from 'master' to 'master', you will find it is not accepted.

[image]

The detection of whether the 'sourcebranch' and 'targetbranch' are the same is high priority, even before the detection of the existence of the branch, so what you want to achieve is not possible from the basic of the design.